# Reusing a component in lit-element

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

Anyone that can point to any documentation on howto reuse code in lit-element.

The problem now is that if I declare an element, in my case a `close-button` and I want to reuse it by importing it into 2 or more lit-elements, there will be an error in the browser about the `close-button` being declared more than once.

Understandable enough, but how do I reuse a component, I could of course move the button to a separate file and add it to the document, but then there would be dependencies on that for other components to work.

Any suggestions

Comment: You can put your element on a repo site like npm, and load it with your package.json. If you don't want to use npm, you could install something like Nexus Repository OSS 3.0 (https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/repository-oss) and manage your own repository (this is what I've done).

Comment: I get that, but then you will actually take a dependency to something outside of your component, and that is something you do not want.. I guess

Answer (score 1):

If `close-button` self-registers itself, with a call to `customElements.define('close-button', ...)`, then you should be able to import its defining module and not have any errors due to the module caching behavior of JS.

You must have multiple `customElements.define('close-button', ...)` calls, so I'd make sure that 1) it's self-registering and you're not registering it again in each component that uses it, and 2) you're using standard JS modules.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating a bit more, I concluded that sharing HTML templates might be the way to do it.

Comment: You can explore option of Scoped Elements from open-wc.org
https://open-wc.org/scoped-elements/